# Titanium Window barColor white

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm trying to set the `barColor` for one of my windows to `#ffffff` or even `white` but it stays gray.

Setting the `barColor` to anything else (any hex code or color name) changes the bar color without a problem.

Is there a reason white color is not acceptable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think its not grey but translucent white. Try setting your window to "translucent:false"